# Does Google adsense affect page ranking?

Tags: google-adsense, pagerank

does placing google ads in out web page help in SEO page rank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Although you may find your pages crawled more frequently as a result of Google attempting to keep the ads relevant to your page's content.

Comment: John, I won't agree with you here. A lot of people in the SEO industry have been testing this very aspect. And even though there isn't a huge effect is seems like there is a slightly negative effect in the rankings for using adsense. There is an article on SEOMOZ that might help you with the information you are seeking: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/guide-to-ads Regards
Justian

Answer (score 0):

The author over here clearly states that pagerank affects the ad quality, and hence your adsense income

http://wsm4b.com/pagerank-adsense/why-google-pagerank-important-making-money-google-adsense